# Flexible presentation of a user's name based on a combination of available properties

Tags: javascript, formatting

The goal is to add a new `displayValue` property to each object depending on what it has available out of `Firstname`, `Lastname`, `Nickname` and `Name`.

I'd like this cleaned up.

```
var data = [
    {
        Id: 132,
        Name: null,
        Firstname: "Sam",
        Lastname: null,
        Nickname: "Dim",

    },
    {
        Id: 162,
        Name: null,
        Firstname: "Junior",
        Lastname: "Dimmer",
        Nickname: null,
    },
    {
        Id: 132,
        Firstname: null,
        Lastname: null,
        Nickname: "Dimmest",
    },
    {
        Name: "No Light",
        Id: 132,
        Firstname: null,
        Lastname: null,
        Nickname: null
    }
]




function formatPeople(data) {

    var yesProp = function (prop) {
        return data[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) && data[i][prop] !== null;
    }

    var noProp = function (prop) {
        return data[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) && data[i][prop] === null;
    }

    for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        // if it has the property Name
        if (yesProp('Name')) {
            data[i].displayValue = data[i].Name;
        }
        if (yesProp('Lastname')) {
            if (yesProp('Firstname')) {
                // if it has the property Lastname and Firstname
                data[i].displayValue = data[i].Lastname + ', ' + data[i].Firstname;
            } else {
                if (yesProp('Nickname')) {
                    // if it has the property Lastname and Nickname but not Firstname
                    data[i].displayValue = data[i].Lastname + ', ' + data[i].Nickname;
                } else {
                    // if it has the property Lastname but not Firstname or Nickname
                    data[i].displayValue = data[i].Lastname;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (yesProp('Firstname')) {
                if (yesProp('Nickname')) {
                    // if it does not have the property Lastname but does have Firstname and Nickname
                    data[i].displayValue = data[i].Firstname + ', ' + data[i].Nickname;
                } else {
                    // if it does not have the property Lastname or Nickname but does have Firstname
                    data[i].displayValue = data[i].Firstname;
                }
            } else {
                if (yesProp('Nickname')) {
                    // if it does not have the property Lastname or Firstname but does have Nickname
                    data[i].displayValue = data[i].Nickname;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return data;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## First

Idiomatic javascript is to camelCase property names. consider the following:

```
{
    name: "No Light",
    id: 132,
    firstname: null,
    lastname: null,
    nickname: null
}
```

Your `yesProp` and `noProp` variables are very bad design. Hoisting allows the `i` variable to be in scope through es3 (to my recollection), but you should never try to take advantage of that. These functions should be rewritten to take the object they are operating on as a parameter.

Additionally, unless there should be some third undefined state, the opposite of `yesProp` should be `!yesProp`, not a different detection method.

`yesProp` is a poor description for the method as well. Consider something describing what it does like `hasProperty`.

Consider the following:

```
function hasNotNullProperty(target, property) {
    return target.hasOwnProperty(property) && target[property] !== null;
}
```

## Second

Javascript is a truthy language, `undefined` and `null` are considered false. Your `yesProp` and my `hasNotNullProperty` method can go away entirely with a simple `if (target[property]) { /* do stuff */ }`. If the property is undefined or evaluates to a falsy value, then it will not execute the block.

Again in this section, `data` is a poor description of what we are expecting. Consider using a more descriptive value such as `people`.

There is no need to `return data;` at the end of the function -- You've modified the objects that were passed in.

Consider the following:

```
function formatPeople(people) {
    for (var i = 0, len = people.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        var displayName;

        // Lastname was defined and not null
        if (people[i].lastname) {
            displayName = people[i].lastname;
            // Firstname was defined and not null
            if (people[i].firstname) {
                displayName+= ', ' + people[i].firstname;
            }
            // Firstname was not defined or was null, but Nickname is defined and not null
            else if (data[i].nickname) {
                displayName += ', ' + people[i].nickname;
            }
        }
        // Lastname was undefined or null, but Firstname is defined and not null
        else if (people[i].firstname) {
            displayName = people[i].firstname;
            if (people[i].Nickname) {
                displayName += ', ' + people[i].nickname;
            }
        }
        // Lastname and Firstname were undefined or null, Nickname is defined and not null
        else if (people[i].nickname) {
            displayName = people[i].nickname;
        }

        if (displayName) {
            people[i].displayValue = displayName
        }
    }
}
```

That still leaves a lot of duplicate code. We will want to clean that up.

## Finally

The truthy nature of javascript allows us to do this as well:

```
var falsy = null;
var truthy = {}; // an anonymous object
var isDefinedAndNotNull = undefined || falsy || truthy; // assigns truthy to isDefinedAndNotNull
```

This allows us to short-circuit the assignment of a value such as a name.

Let's remove some of that duplicate code, and make a few more names clearer.

```
function setDisplayNamesForPeople(people) {
    var lastname, firstname, nickname, defaultName, displayName;

    for (var i = 0, length = people.length; i < length; i++) {
        lastname = people[i].lastname;
        firstname = people[i].firstname;
        nickname = people[i].nickname;
        defaultname = people[i].name;
        displayName = formatName(lastname, firstname, nickname, defaultname);

        if (displayName) {
            people[i].displayValue = displayName;
        }
    }
}

//formatName format is (lastname [', ' (firstname | nickname)] | (firstname [', ' nickname]) | nickname | defaultname)
function formatName(lastname, firstname, nickname, defaultname) {
    var formattedName = "";
    if (lastname && (firstname || nickname)) {
        formattedName = ', ' + (firstname || nickname);
    }
    else if (firstname && nickname) {
        formattedName = ', ' + nickname;
    }

    formattedName = (lastname || firstname || nickname || defaultname) + formattedName;

    return formattedName;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the detailed feedback. Just wondering if the use of `default` was a mistake? Not sure I understand that. Thanks again!

Comment: I forgot `default` can be a keyword. `defaultname` would be more appropriate I suppose. **fixed**

Comment: What you've done is great. It all makes a lot of sense looking at the finished product. I'm very grateful for that. I will do some further reading on short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

This code is not exactly equivalent to your code,
but for the given sample input it gives the same output:

```
function combineAttributes(obj, names) {
    var name = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
        if (obj[names[i]]) {
            name += ', ' + obj[names[i]];
        }
    }
    return name.length ? name.substr(2) : null;
}

function formatPeople(arr) {
    var names = ['Name', 'Lastname', 'Firstname', 'Nickname'];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        var obj = arr[i];
        obj.displayValue = combineAttributes(obj, names);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Even if this is not exactly what you're looking for,
it could be a good starting point to improve on.

#### Invalid JavaScript

This is invalid:

> ```
> {
>     Name: "No Light"
>     Id: 132,
>     Firstname: null,
>     Lastname: null,
>     Nickname: null,
> }
> ```

There should be a comma after `Name: "No Light"`.

There shouldn't be a comma after `Nickname`.